# Divide a tile map into multiple images

Tags: tilemap, tiled, tiles, tilesets

So let's say I have a tilemap 5 x 5, which equals 25 tiles.

How can I divide my tilemap into 25 different images? I'm using tiled, but I don't know if it is possible to do it on there or if I need to use one other program.
Of course, my tilemap is bigger than 5 x 5, so it's why I'm asking because it would consume a lot of my time.

Thanks.

Comment: Just to make sure you have a tile map base image file, and you want to produce 25 different image files based on that input file?

Comment: A [sprite sheet cutter](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=sprite+sheet+cutter) can be used to split up a tilemap, however that's not usually how tilemaps are utilized. For example if you have a 200 x 100 tilemap, you don't load them as 20,000 separate images. What's your end goal for dividing your tilemap?